# Issue with pyenv install

Tags: pyenv

I have an issue installing pyenv... can somebody help me ?

I ran

`sudo apt-get install -y make build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev python-openssl`

Then I installed pyenv by

`curl https://pyenv.run | bash`

But when I want install a python version, for example :

```
$ pyenv install 3.7.10
Downloading Python-3.7.10.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.10/Python-3.7.10.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.7.10...
patching file Misc/NEWS.d/next/Build/2021-10-11-16-27-38.bpo-45405.iSfdW5.rst
patching file configure
patching file configure.ac

BUILD FAILED (Debian 11 using python-build 2.3.26)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/python-build.20230907152001.230796
Results logged to /tmp/python-build.20230907152001.230796.log

Last 10 log lines:
  File "/tmp/python-build.20230907152001.230796/Python-3.7.10/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 32, in _run_pip
    runpy.run_module("pip", run_name="__main__", alter_sys=True)
  File "/tmp/python-build.20230907152001.230796/Python-3.7.10/Lib/runpy.py", line 201, in run_module
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name)
  File "/tmp/python-build.20230907152001.230796/Python-3.7.10/Lib/runpy.py", line 142, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "/tmp/python-build.20230907152001.230796/Python-3.7.10/Lib/runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
make: *** [Makefile:1141 : install] Erreur 1
```

I get an error, does someone have an idea ?

Thanks :)

I tried reinstalling pyenv but it did nothing